# python: label position lineplot() with secondary y-axes

Tags: python, plot

I have a produce a plot with secondary y-axes and the labels are on top of each other:
[image]

The code is the following:

```
    sns.lineplot(data=incident_cnt["A"], ax=ax,color="#FF4613", marker='o')
    sns.lineplot(data=incident_cnt["B"], ax=ax, color="#80D5FF", marker='o')
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(data=incident_cnt["C"], ax=ax2, color="#00FFAA", marker='o')
    ax.set_xlabel("Date of index event")
    ax.set_ylabel("Patients (no)")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Patients (no) - DIC", color="#00FFAA")
    ax2.set_ylim(0, ax.get_ylim()[1]/10)
```

is there a way to manually change the position of label C so it does not get on top of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to remove the individual legends (ax and ax2) and use the figure level legend. Note that you need to add the labels for A, B, C while creating the lineplot. The updated code is below. Note that I have used the seaborn provided flights data as I don't have your data... should be similar for your data as well. Hope this is what you are looking for

```
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights_wide = flights.pivot("year", "month", "passengers")
#flights_wide.columns = flights_wide.columns.get_level_values(0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=flights_wide["May"], ax=ax, color="#FF4613", marker='o', label='A') ## Add label for A
sns.lineplot(data=flights_wide["Jun"], ax=ax, color="#80D5FF", marker='o', label='B') ## Add label for b
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=flights_wide["Jul"], ax=ax2, color="#00FFAA", marker='o', label='C') ## Add label for C
ax.set_xlabel("Date of index event")
ax.set_ylabel("Patients (no)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Patients (no) - DIC", color="#00FFAA")
ax.get_legend().remove() # Remove ax legend
ax2.get_legend().remove() # Remove ax2 legend
fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
```

...resulting in plot

[image]